# Broadcasting in spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, broadcast

How can I broadcast a dstream computed over a window? For instance, for the last 10 minute I find the subset of lines satisfying a condition (call it send_events dstream). I need to find a set of lines satisfying another condition (call it ack_events_for_send_events dstream) in the last 10 minutes using the send_events dstream.  I do not want to groupbykey due to large shuffling. When I do groupbykey, the size of each group is very small like at most 10. In other words, I have lots of groups (I am not sure if this helps to optimize my operations. Just wanted to share.)

Example:

```
id1, type1, time1
id1, type2, time3
id2, type1, time5
id1, type1, time2
id2, type2, time4
id1, type2, time6
```

I want to find the minimum time difference between type1 and type2 per id. Each id has at most 10 lines, but I have 10,000 ids in a given window

Comment: Take on look to the documentation on broadcast variables [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables), it is quite easy. Anyhow, from your description I'm not sure what is the right solution for your problem. Please post the code you already have if you want a more effective and concrete answer.

Comment: I have actually read the documentation several times. Within the spark, it is easy to understand. I can collect the RDD and then broadcast it, my main problem is to broadcast the DStream which is a series of RDDs. It should be simple but there is no collect function for DStreams. There is a foreachRDD function which might help but I could not figure out how to use it to collect all the data in the DStream. Thanks for your comment btw.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following would work?

```
yourDStream.foreachRDD(somefunc)
```

Then in somefunc:

```
def somefunc(rdd):
    broadcastedList=sc.broadcast(rdd.collect())
```